# How can I run a python method after N seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python method `get_current_build_time()`that fetches current build time (in second) of a server which gets updated every seconds
I would like to run the same method after 2 second to get the current build time and assert they are not equal.

However, I get the same time if I try sleep

```
get_current_build_time()
sleep(2)
get_current_build_time()
```

Is there any better way to do do this?

Expected outcome:

```
get_current_build_time() >> 10
sleep(2)
get_current_build_time() >> 12
```

Actual outcome:

```
get_current_build_time() >> 10
sleep(2)
get_current_build_time() >> 10
```

Comment: can you describe with code what is in `get_current_build_time()`?

Comment: Need some information on how the get_current_build_time works and how it get the time stamps.

Comment: this would fetch the current build time (in second) of the server which updates every seconds. 

Expected example outcome:

`get_current_build_time()`
`>> 10`
`sleep(1)`
`get_current_build_time()`
`>> 11`

Comment: Maybe you need schedule module?
https://pypi.org/project/schedule/